# How do I get a PEM file into the javascript object required for node-bignumber?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rsa

I want to configure my Node app to decode public key encrypted messages POST'ed to it using its private key. The private key is in PEM format.

I wanted to use a javascript only solution on the server side for maximum portability (hence `ursa` is out), this appear to leave `node-bignumber` ( on the phone app side, I will be using C# and probably something like [Scrypt](http://scrypt.codeplex.com/)). The [single example given for node-bignumber](https://npmjs.org/package/node-bignumber) seems to work well so long as yo use the `Key` method to generate the certificate, however I already have certificates (the public one installed in my phone app and the private one used by my server) - how do I get this into a format recognised by the the library?

I admit I am totally new to NodeJS and javascript and would greatly appreciate any more general advice you may have in providing backends for phone apps ...

Comment: PEM to DER conversion is just a Base 64 decoding .. I am not sure what is the format required by node-bignumber u mentioned . But PEM and DER are the 2 formats used to store keys and certificates

Comment: The format required is a Javascript object, each field corresponds to a field in the private key - I was looking for a way to take a `.pem` file and create this object ...

Comment: hey, did you found how to do it?

Comment: @Asaf I wanted to do this so I could send data back and forth between my app (and only my app) and NodeJS backend securely. In the end I just used https with a shared secret in the app and the NodeJS server passed in the POST request - much easier!